# How to read the file from Project Structure

Tags: java, jsp

I want to read the file from the project structure.
[image: Projrct Structure]

My intention is to list Basic&Premium and Merchant-Address files which is under
Report/Adhoc folder

I tried some approch but i could't make it.

Please help me. i am struck here from last 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using java.io.File class for your problem ?

```
File file = new File(
    getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(//your file path here).getFile()
);
```